# Background image url() not compliling using sass

Tags: html, css, sass, compilation, background

I am using Live Sass Compiler in VS code. Earlier I was using Node JS for conversion of sass into css. The code works fine but I don't see any background-image url() in css. Also it does not show background in output. Path for the image in scss file is correct. I am using variables for that.

```
$show-home-image: true;
$home-image: url(../img/background.jpg);
$background-opacity: 0.9;
@mixin background {
  @if $show-home-image {
    &#bg-img {
      background: $home-image;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: cover;
```

Comment: What is `@if $show-home-image`? Delete it.

Comment: a subset of  $show-home-image: true